# Page Titles Being Translated into Multiple Languages in Google Analytics Reports (GA4)

Tags: google-analytics, analytics, webflow

I am looking at a website report for last month in Google Analytics, and each page title is showing up multiple times in different languages.

I've tried looking into this online, and it seems like people are saying that the title is being translated through Google Translate into the language matching the country where the user is browsing from. Is this true? And if so, is there anyway to stop this from happening? I would prefer to just have each page title included once in English -- is this possible?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it's exactly what's happening most likely.

Usually people just don't use titles for any meaningful reporting. They instead use page url or page path.

And yes, of course you can prevent it. You can override the default `dt` (document title) parameter in the call and set it with whatever value you deem appropriate, but you likely won't be able to take the value from DOM since that's exactly what the default tracking is attempting to do.